# Obtaining the critical solution for a functional

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-principle

So, I was trying to calculate the critical solution $y = y(x)$ for the following functional:

$$J[y] = \int_{0}^{1} (y'^{\: 2} + y^2 + 2ye^x)dx$$

and a professor of mine said I should use conservation theorem and use Euler-Lagrange's equation afterwards, but Noether's conservation theorem states that we can write

$$y' \dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y'} - F = C, \:\: C \in \mathbb{R}$$

only if the function $F(y,y',x)$ does not depend explicitly on $x$, which is not the case on the functional above. So I went and just applyed Euler-Lagrange's equation directly, namely

$$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y} - \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial y'}\right) = 0$$

and solved the second order ODE that comes from this by wronskian and all to obtain a $y(x)$ solution, but I think I'm wrong at taking this problem this way. I'd like to know if I'm right or wrong on this calculations, and if I'm wrong I honestly don't know how to proceed on this.

Comment: I can't see an obvious symmetry to use Noether's theorem here either- directly solving the ODE is valid.

Comment: Yeah, by the Euler-Lagrange's equation I got $y'' - y = e^x$ and solved it for $y$ using known methods, but the message I received from my professor states that "if I use the conservation equation and then apply Euler-Lagrange's equation, I should get $y$ in an easier way". Anyway, thanks :)